# how to set image in mobile web in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, image, mobile-website

I have a mobile website created for one of my clients. I created a site on my development server and live server. When I upload an image logo on the development server and check it on mobile, the image is displayed properly. But when I put the same code on my live server, the image is not shown on mobile but is shown on my PC.

I am just using simple HTML:

`<img src="/image/logo.jpg">`

I even tried the code below with and without quotes in the image URL.

`<div style="background-image: url(/image/logo.jpg)" />`

Comment: a link to live site would help a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use an image control. Just drag it from the toolbox in Visual Studio and set the image in the properties panel:

```
<asp:Image ID="MyImage" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/image/logo.jpg" />
```

Then you'll never have to worry about paths because ASP.NET will always make sure it correctly chooses the path to your image.

Now if your only using HTML, your problem is super simple. Try removing the first slash. That should do the trick.

```
<img src="image/logo.jpg"/>
```

Or if your trying to add it as background in a div:

```
<div style="background-image: url("image/logo.jpg");"></div>
```

And for your reference check out this page directly from MSDN that explains pretty much every possible way to link to images in a website:

[ASP.NET Web Site Paths](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178116%28l=en-us,v=VS.90%29.aspx)

Let me know if this helps.

Answer (score 0):

To resolve it, use the following syntax:

> < img src="~/image/logo.jpg" alt="Don't forget the alt"
>   runat="server">

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out the problem is with the path to the image directory. We're assuming that the image directory resides in the root of your app. The leading / refers to the root URL of your site. Using ~/ in server controls will cause asp.net to replace this with the root URL of you app. 
Here are some examples that might clarify:

www.example.com/someApp/image/logo.jpg

```
/image/logo.jpg = www.example.com/image/logo.jpg
```

Broken link. This refers to a directory outside of your app. If it worked on your development server then it must have an image directory at it's root.

```
image/logo.jpg = www.example.com/someApp/image/logo.jpg
```

This will work as long as the link resides in the root of the app.

```
~/image/logo.jpg = www.example.com/someapp/image/logo.jpg
```

This will work regardless of where the link resides. But the control containing the link must be set to runat="server".

Answer (score 0):

I think your html is not well formatted for mobile.

Put this at beginning of your html file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//WAPFORUM//DTD XHTML Mobile 1.0//EN" "http://www.wapforum.org/DTD/xhtml-mobile10.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
```

And then check if it's displayed properly.

Also check the web site with another mobile phone and remember that old files may be cached by your ISP.

***P.S:*** Using image tag like this is OK:

```
<img alt="the image" src="/image/logo.jpg" />
```

***P.P.S:*** Is your image tag closed properly? It's missing a **"/"**.

Test this:

```
<img src="/image/logo.jpg" />
```

Comment: this won't fix the fact that you can't find the path to the image. It might make it valid but it certainly won't fix a broken link.

Comment: @loyal: I agree, but it seems like that the tag is working on a PC so i assumed that the link is not broken. But it will be a very good idea to check if it's broken or not.